# In laravel , how to prevent TeamMember(user) from accessing specific routes?

Tags: laravel, permissions, middleware, roles

I'm building an Rest API for a mobile app where i have the following tables :

1. User table ( with user details )
2. Team table ( related to user through a user_id column )
3. Roles table ( list of roles )
4. permission( list of permissions)
5. role_team_user ( pivot table to
   relate a user in a specific team with a specific role )

so for example user ( john ) in a team ( team_id : 1 ) has a role as ( Team leader) and the same user ( john ) could belongs to another team ( team_id : 3 ) with a role as (assistant)

team leader can have all the permission to add, delete , update and so on , but the assistant is allowed to edit only ( as an example ) ,

what i want to do , is to use a middleware to allow john to have all the permissions in the first team projects ( as a Team Leader ) , but to prevent him from all the permissions except for ( editing - as per the example ) .

how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done with roles, I recommend you checking the following [package (spatie/laravel-permission)](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) for that.

For your project, you will have to seed a database with the roles and permissions, then you establish a user as a super-admin and define that as in the docs say to later on give the roles to each employee.

Comment: this is done already , i have sfilled the table with the roles and permissions related , but to to configure these cases in the middleware ? how to write the conditions ?

Comment: My link is a documentation, please READ the docs. Everything you need yo know is there, you DON'T really need middlewares.